# Finding haskell higher-order functions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, function-composition, pointfree

A function which zips a list onto itself can be defined as:

```
let adjacent1 l = zip l $ tail l
```

This works, but I'd like to define it in pointfree style. To do this, I define a function `dollarize`:

```
let dollarize f1 f2 x = f1 x $ f2 x
let adjacent1 = dollarize zip tail
```

This works, but obviously I'd rather not define my own higher-order functions. Is there a way to find the standard equivalent of `dollarize`, assuming it exists? And if not, where are the functions of this sort which exist to combine functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`pointfree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree) tool can do this for you automagically.

```
$ pointfree "\l -> zip l (tail l)"
ap zip tail
$ pointfree "\f1 f2 x -> f1 x $ f2 x"
ap
```

Comment: If you are a regular IRC user, the `lambdabot` of `#haskell` can do the same thing. Just query it `@pl \l -> zip l (tail l)` and you'll get the same answer.

Answer (score 6):

How about using the `Applicative` instance of `(->) a`?

```
Prelude Control.Applicative> :t zip <*> tail
zip  <*> tail :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
Prelude Control.Applicative> zip <*> tail $ [1 .. 4]
[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
```

short and sweet.

Comment: Yes, just checked that, wasn't sure.

Comment: It's obvious if you remember that `<$>` on functions is just function composition, and composing with `id` obviously does nothing. Also worth mentioning that `<*>` is the S combinator from SKI calculus.

Comment: Which would help if I knew SKI calculus ;)

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of thing I would like to do, but how would I find `<*>`, if I don't know about it?

Comment: @Marcin: Normally, I recommend [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/). However, it won't find the answer in this case, since it treats the function arrow `(->)` specially, so it never finds functions which rely on using `(a ->)` as a monad/applicative, so searching for `f (b -> c) -> f b -> f c` works, but not `(a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`.

Answer (score 3):

Accoring to @Daniel Fischer's answer. Also your can use monad instance of `(->) a`:

```
Prelude Control.Monad.Instances> let adjacent1 = tail >>= flip zip
Prelude Control.Monad.Instances> adjacent1 [1..4]
[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
```